# using setvalue in the ondatachange with same class

Tags: android, firebase

I want to read data from firebase to increment the data and write back into the firebase. This is my function:

```
        StatData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Statistic");

        Getstat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Statistic");
        Getstat.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Stat stat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Stat.class);
                int count = stat.getStatP();
                int statP = count + 1;
                Stat a = new Stat(statP);
                StatData.setValue(a);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I am using the same class Stat for read and write the data. Can it be use?

Comment: I suppose it'll work...but you'll get an endless loop. Every time you catch a change in `GetStat` listener, you'll increment the counter and catch the new changes in `GetStat` listener and increment it again...Are you sure this is what you want to do? This is because both references are for the same path in you database

Comment: Basically I just want to increment it once. For example Getstat read data from firebase which is 1, then after increment to become 2 Statdata will write back it into firebase as value 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a value to to a node that is based on the current value of that node, [use a Firebase transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). Your example would be something like this:

```
postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Stat stat = mutableData.getValue(Stat.class);
        if (stat == null) {
            // Node doesn't exist or its value isn't known yet => return success
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }
        int count = stat.getStatP();
        int statP = count + 1;
        stat = new Stat(statP);

        // Set value and report transaction success
        mutableData.setValue(p);
        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Transaction completed
        Log.d(TAG, "statTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help